# How to take the screen-shot of the current video frame in the videoView android?

Tags: android, media, android-videoview

I am using the video-view to play media and I want to take the screen shot of the current frame. I found some solutions which include using mediaMetaDataRetriever but that method is way too slow and does not perform well in many cases.
I can not use media player over texture view to capture view I knew that approach, because I need by default media controls in my app.
Is there any way to make that process fast?
My CODE:

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapVideoView(){
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever;
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            int currentPosition =videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getVideoURL(),new HashMap<String, String>());
            Bitmap bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(currentPosition*1000);
            if (bitmap != null) {
//                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
//                textureview.draw(canvas);
                return bitmap;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("Errorrr",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Approach:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Screenshot.INSTANCE.with((MainActivity)activity).setView(findViewById(R.id.relative)).setQuality(Quality.HIGH).getScreenshot();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    Toast toastShot = null;
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.screen));
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.shot_image);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    toastShot = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toastShot.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toastShot.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastShot.setView(layout);
                    toastShot.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For taking screenshot you can use this library

```
implementation 'com.github.MindorksOpenSource:screenshot:v0.0.1'
```

And for taking screenshot just call this function on button click or any other event

```
 var b = Screenshot.with(activity!!).setView(rl_imageText).setQuality(Quality.HIGH).getScreenshot()
```

**Note: rl_imageText** = This is the id of my xml relative layout of which i am taking screenshot.

It will provide you the bitmap of the screenshot and for saving it into the storage or getting path use the below mentioned function

```
private fun getImageUriFromBitmap(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap): Uri {
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
    val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.contentResolver, bitmap,"Title",null)
    return Uri.parse(path.toString())
}
```

Note: Please mention if it will not work so that i will provide you other solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply but the mentioned library is giving errors while syncing the project.

Comment: It's synced now, I will let you know if I encounter any problem in taking screen shot.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code. But it is giving only black screen not the frame that is being played. I have added the code above please have a look.

Comment: Have you passed the correct id either of your view or layout in which you have placed your view.

Comment: yes, even I tried with different layouts such as image view. These all working fine but when I apply it on videoView it gives a black screen maybe it is picking up the root view of videoView.